# Adding users to Facebook Custom Audience without any roles of Facebook app

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I'm currently working in a service that allow to create Custom Audience and add users to Audiences

Everything works fine when I'm the developer or admin of the app

But when I'm trying to add users by another account without any roles of the app, it return an exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException'
(Both are Ads Account Advertisers of the ad account)

I did some searching around and found that
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522478074583401/

> If a person wants to add users to a custom audience by specifying their (app-scoped) user IDs for a given app, the person needs to have access to these user IDs.
>   This access is determined by this person's role on the app (they need to be a developer or admin of the app), or by the person being an advertiser for the app. Neither of these two conditions are met in the case of your API call.

Anyone please declare "the person being an advertiser for the app" for me please?

And are there any way to add users to an audience without any roles of the app?

Can't find this in docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users/

Answer (score 0):

I guess most likely your app is still in the Development or the Basic access mode.

Documentation:- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

When in Development/Basic mode, your app could only manage up to 5/25 Ad Accounts respectively and you have to add them to the app explicitly in App->Settings->Advanced->Advertising Accounts. Add the Advertiser's account ID both here and in the 'Ads API' section (this is most likely what they meant by adding the person to be an advertiser for the app).

If you want to add users to an audience in an Advertiser account without any roles in the app, you'll have to send your app through reviews and earn the Standard access mode. The steps to do this are detailed in the link above.

Also, developers and admins by default get all the permissions granted to them. You need to check if you have other Facebook permissions that you might be requesting (such as 'manage_pages'), as you will need to get these permissions approved through review as well before it will work without adding them to roles. You can submit your app for review under the App->App Review section.